# Screen support for mobile phones, not tablet

Tags: android, screen-resolution

[**This**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) provides a very deep insight for handling multiple screen resolutions in the application. And here I am still confused. This reference says

> As you design your UI for different screen sizes, you'll discover that
>   each design requires a minimum amount of space. So, each generalized
>   screen size above has an associated minimum resolution that's defined
>   by the system. These minimum sizes are in "dp" units—the same units
>   you should use when defining your layouts—which allows the system to
>   avoid worrying about changes in screen density.
>
> ```
> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
> ```

This is where I have got confused. Aren't these the landscape/ tablet dimensions ? For a mobile phone isn't this just the opposite ?
So, does it has to be, say `320dp x 426dp` for a phone or is there something I haven't understood ?
Also, what will be the portrait resolutions I have to consider.

Comment: try reading this if it's useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is where I have got confused.

At this point, landscape/portrait are not yet in the picture. Consider this:

```
A: What are the dimensions of an A4 sheet?
B: 8.5" x 11"
```

Another version:

```
A: What are the dimensions of an A4 sheet?
B: In what orientation are you holding the sheet?
A: Landscape
B: 11" x 8.5"
```

---

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

The above dimensions are being reported using landscape as the orientation.

> Aren't these the landscape/ tablet dimensions ? For a mobile phone
>   isn't this just the opposite ?

Not when you have decided that all dimensions are going to be reported in landscape orientation.

> So, does it has to be, say 320dp x 426dp for a phone or is there
>   something I haven't understood? Also, what will be the portrait
>   resolutions I have to consider.

Since we've established the dimensions in landscape, flipping these will give us the portrait *dimensions* - resolution is an entirely different, orientation-independent, classification criterion.

Comment: Thanks Vikram for your clear answer. Can you also answer the last part though. Also, what will be the portrait resolutions I have to consider.

Comment: @Nitish The dimensions above are only for reference. When you start designing layouts, you should consider what minimum width your layout requires. Starting off, design a layout that will look okay on a 300dp-wide screen. This will cover small & normal screen sizes. Next, decide if you want to provide a different layout for when you have more space - for example, on a tablet, you might want to show a two-pane / multi-pane layout. Again, calculate how much space you need for that - say 600dp. Create your two-pane layout and place it in `layout-sw600dp`. There's no need for absolute dimensions.

Comment: @Nitish It could be that I'm not able to understand your question. [In that case, we can continue the discussion in chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73686/screen-support-for-mobile-phones-not-tablet).

Comment: @Nitish Thanks for the bounty, but I get the feeling that I haven't answered your question(s) fully. Could you rephrase your question, so that I can give it another shot?

Comment: :) Actually I am an iOS developer. This is the first Android app for me. I am experiencing difficulty in implementing image sizes for the app. I guess there are many changes I have to make to concur this. Like image resolutions plus the layout variants. Since Android runs on I don't know 100's of phones with different sizes, it's really difficult to take care of this. Can you please provide a precise/ complete solution which  I should follow while taking into account images and layouts for different screen sizes.

Comment: @Nitish I can answer your concerns. But this will take some time and I don't want to litter the comment space here. That's why I suggested this chat room: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73686/screen-support-for-mobile-phones-not-tablet).

Comment: It was a great session Vikram shared with me on this. I am glad, I am clear now on what I asked for. Thanks to Vikram and his thorough knowledge on the subject. Please refer to the chat link for the detail explanation Vikram has shared.