# Same imageview size in xml - different on device

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me with strange issue. I have simple linear layout with three imageviews, with same sizes. It look normal in Android Studio design, but on the device third imageview has different size. How to fix it? p.s. image resources have same sizes

part of layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="60dp"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:gravity="center"
                              android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/twitterlb"
                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                               android:layout_width="60dp"
                               android:src="@drawable/tw_circle" android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/facebooklb"
                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                               android:layout_width="60dp"
                               android:src="@drawable/fb_circle" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                               android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/linkedinlb"
                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                               android:layout_width="60dp"
                               android:src="@drawable/in_circle" android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

in Android studio:

[image: buttons looks same in Android studio]

on device:

[image: on device]

Comment: Try giving `android:layout_height="60dp"` for all three ImageViews. And give your LinearLayout  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This way, you will take in account the extra margin/padding dps.

Comment: thanks, but already tried, same problem. also tried to run on different devices and clean/rebuild project and reinstall app

Comment: So try using `android:background` instead of `android:src`

Comment: is ur studio design emulator and ur device is of same resolution? if not crosscheck ur images size to confirm all drawable folders images are same in size..

Comment: give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/linkedinlb"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_width="60dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/in_circle"
                   android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

You may try to change scaleType's to **fitXY**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I finally solved the problem. The problem was: **same** similar res for drawable-mdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-nodpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, 
drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, but **different** for drawable-xhdpi (5 pixels transparent frame)