# ANDROID: How to have different devices use different layouts?

Tags: android, screen, resolution

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I just can't figure it out. I am making an app where it looks fine on my phone, an LG G3 here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z0m9.jpg

However, on my friends, a cheaper nexus with lower resolution, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ha6P.jpg

Using the lower resolution phone in android studio, I have created a layout that works for the other phone. However, how would I have this phone use this layout?

Thanks! ☺

Comment: 1) There are a lot of resource directory modifiers you can use: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.  Just use layout-hdpi or whatever.

Comment: 2) You probably should be making your layout responsive across all screen densities, though.  Making another layout is probably just masking the real problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android devices with different height takes same layout folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder)