# Combining different dimensions for different devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I found solution for different layouts:

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

and for dimensions

```
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
```

Can I combine? Example:

```
res/values-sw560dp/dimens.xml
```

If I open application on Nexus 6(560dpi), I want to use dimens from my `res/values-sw560dp/dimens.xml`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to get more info you should take a look at part of Android doc about [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it well explains all possibility of qualifiers combinations.

You should also read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085) anwser, posted by Pankaj Nimgade