# Android Different Screen Sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working in Android Studio, this app is aiming to target devices from API 10, several features I am using for supporting old and new devices I am getting from appcompat library.

When I test in my phone, the app design seems Ok, but I know I have to mantain compatibility for other devices, like tablets. Untill now, I only have created folders in drawable, for different screen densities (mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi...).

The point is how can I support different sizes (i.e. one layout for small phones, other for tablets...). I heard about create folders in layout like small, medium and large, but in Google developers site, this is not recommended, I should use intead sw...dp, however it seems is supported only for api 13 and above.

I am considering make an app for phones and other for tablets, unless there is something I can do, keeping support for api 10 and above and supporting different screen sizes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085 give this a try

Comment: Pankahj, I saw your post, the doubt I have now, does the qualifier in layout "w... - h ..." works in Api 10?

Comment: well, i am not sure but this is quite an old technique to support multi screen devices so it should work on them, i would rather suggest targeting API 16 and above as it covers most of the mobile available in market

Comment: Pankah, Thank you, as I'm seeing, my old android 2.3 have to retire...

Comment: sorry mate all good things come to end.

Remember what Batman says **Either you die a Hero, or live long enough to be hated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, in the android documentation you can find (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge
>   Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are
>   deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based
>   on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2
>   and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more
>   information.

It tells you to not use them just if you are designing for API 13 and above. If you don't then you should use the deprecated identifiers.

I don't think make an app for an API lower than 15 has much sense, here you can see some charts of API distribution:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/dashboards/index.html

With API 15 you are covering the 96.4% of the users.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have an android 2.3 phone, that's why I am developing from api 10 and above... But I am seeing it is hard to develop also for covering below api 15

Comment: I guessed that was the reason, but when developing software we must take care of the user, and with so low api you are going to lose some functionalities. You could try the emulator but it can go very slow, I have an older computer (+5 years) and preffer to not use it. Ask santa for a new device, it's xmas!

Comment: I hope Santa remember me... but while my new phone is delaying I'll limit screen support on manifest for only phones for now... I think it will be easier...

Comment: You can just provide phone interface on tablet then. No need to lock the app for phones only.