# How to create graphics for Android App for different resolution to support for different Phone size?

Tags: android, android-image

I am preparing graphics for my App.First I prepare graphics of xxhdpi resolution normal screen(samsung galaxy s4) using photoshop.
Now to support for other resolution i have converted using resolution ratio for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi.

```
ldpi | mdpi | tvdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
0.75 | 1    | 1.33  | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4
```

My problem is new xhdpi graphics prepared is looking blur or distorted on Nexus 10 xhdpi device(also on small 2.7" ldpi devices).How to create the graphics to support such multi-resolution and various screen size devices.

Comment: give this a look.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the xhdpi image has the correct resolution?

How have you generated the images for different screen densities?

To support different screen densities ( if you don't need 9patch ), create an image at the resolution that fits good for the maximum screen density that you want to support ( for ex. xxxhdpi ).
Then use this image as input for a resizer tool that generates the corresponding images resized for all the different density screen that you need.

I usually use this tool : https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases

Answer (score 0):

Wse any of these:

- http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
- http://android-holo-colors.com/
- https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html
- http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

These are very helpful for android images.