# Design android app for fitting all screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build an app for android and I created an xml file for a fragment.
 In the preview, which is *Nexus 4* I can see the items`(buttons, text view, etc.)` taking all the space, but when I run my app on my phone (*s6 edge +*) there is like 1/5 of the screen free. 
 My height is set on everything at `wrap_content` and I only use padding in `dp` units.

**How can I go about this problem ? Should I replace all 'wrap content' to a specific value for all heights ?**

My xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="35dp"
        android:text="Title1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Title2"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/first"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/second"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/third"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button3"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button4"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button5"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button6"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button7"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button8"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="65dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you can post the layout, someone may help you, until then kindly try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085

Comment: @PankajNimgade posted the code. The padding is the problem, but I don't know hot to set it without using a specific unit of measure.

Comment: I have posted an answer, i guess that would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i did make some changes,

although i don't really understand which view supposed to do what in your layout. So I made this layout in manner to manage it's space for the multi-screen support, But you should consider making different layout depending on the screen you want to target.

kindly try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="35dp"
            android:text="Title1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Title2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button3"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button4"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button5"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button6"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button7"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:text="button8"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

> Output

[image: output]

> Update

things which you can do to distribute `Views` equilibrium horizontally like this by using `layout_weight` while making their width to `0dp`, in given example I am showing two `Buttons` taking the space horizontally. pay attention to it's `width` and `layout_weight`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="One"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Two"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

if you want two `Views` to take equal space vertically you can use following example, make the `parent layout` have orientation vertical and the `view's` height `0dp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/goku" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/gohan" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: How can I go about setting the width the same way ?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, you can play around with layout_weight while making width="0dp" so your view width will be managed by the percentage provided in layout_weight, erst will be taken care by android framework :)

Comment: but should i make a new linear layout for that ? because i already have it for height in that

Answer (score 0):

You should use layout weights.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

> Layout Weight
>
> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children
>   with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an
>   "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should
>   occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to
>   fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a
>   weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is
>   assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight.
>   Default weight is zero.
>
> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a
>   weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field
>   without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
>   its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space
>   remaining after all three fields are measured. If the third field is
>   then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more
>   important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining
>   space, while the first two share the rest equally.