# How to make my layout scale on different screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, textview

I have simple layout with 4 different levels/modes you can play. Problem is when i preview layout on different screen sizes it doesn't appear same:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mda2i.png)

Here is layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mode1background"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:background="@drawable/mode2background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:background="@drawable/mode3background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:background="@drawable/mode4background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make each `TextView` be 1/4 of screen size.

Comment: try this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025843/android-devices-with-different-height-takes-same-layout-folder/29026085#29026085

Comment: Have you tried with `LinearLayout` , because it has property `android:weight={value}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a vertical `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_weight` attributes.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000000"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/mode1background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/mode2background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/mode3background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/mode4background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Check out the developer's guide on `LinearLayout` and Layout Weight:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: Should my layout_weight be 0.25 or 1 as other answers suggest ? What is difference because it seems to work with 0.25 and 1 as wight.

Comment: It doesn't matter as longs as they are the same. I just prefer when the sum of my weights is 1 :)

Comment: Isn't it different when the sum is 4 (with weights 1) and 1 (with 0.25)

Comment: No it is not. Think of it as an "importance" value. If the weights are equal, then the `View`s will get equal space (they are equally important). If `View` **A**'s weight is twice as much as the weight of `View` **B**, then `View` **A** will get twice as much space as `View` **B**.

Comment: That makes sense :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change parent layout to `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. Then set each child's height to `0dp` and weight to `1`

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Should my layout_weight be 1 or 0.25 as other answers suggest ? What is difference because it seems to work with 0.25 and 1 as wight.

Comment: There is no difference if you don't define weightSum for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

create the following directories in resourcefolder and place different resolution images of background in respective directories

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-hdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-xxhdpi

drawable-xxxhdpi

note the name of image in all folders should be same, android will automatically pick the image from the respective folder depending upon the dpi of phone

Answer (score 0):

As you want to occupy the full height of the device you will need to use linear layout with vertical oreintation and giving attribute 'layout_weight' = 1 for all the TextView.
Sample code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mode1background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="play"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mode2background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="play"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mode3background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="play"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mode4background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="play"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```